# Como faço tabelas menores a partir de um data.frame em R?

Tags: r, tabela-html

Estou com uma tabela em data frame, com 100 animais, mas com 500 observações de várias caracteristicas. como faço pra ter subtabelas, com apenas os animais e a caracteristica x, sendo q ele deve mostrar tds as 500 observaçoes dessa caracteristica X. Detalhe animais está como factor com 100 levels, e observações está como levels tbem, eu queria q ele tivesse só como numeros normais, contem ponto (3.2 4.2 )

tipo 
animal 1   1.1 2.0 1.0 0.2 1.7 .... (500 vezes)
animal 2

Obrigado.

Comment: Fiquei com um pouco de duvida, sobre sua questão, você quer filtrar seu dados e transformar os objetos ou? Talvez  você possa disponibilizar um exemplo dos teus dados.

Answer (score 4):

Em relação ao formato dos dados, se estão como `factor`, o ideal é corrigir isso na leitura dos dados. Valores numéricos lidos como fatores podem ocorrer por algum dos seguintes motivos:

- Sua tabela está transposta: Para o R, os dados devem possuir variáveis (no seu caso, características) nas colunas, e observações (animais) nas linhas. Dessa forma, todas colunas terão mesmo tipo de dado (número, texto, lógico, data, etc).
- Existe conteúdo que não faz parte dos dados, como comentário no início ou fim dos dados.
- Você não leu os dados corretamente. O argumento `stringsAsFactors` é útil para evitar que textos virem fatores (mas não deveria ser necessário para números), e pode ser necessário também usar `skip` ou `row.names`. Só podemos ajudar melhor se você fornecer os dados originais, ou uma amostra representativa deles.

Para separar apenas uma característica (coluna), você pode fazer de várias formas, mas a mais simples é usar o operador `$`, da seguinte forma:

```
animais$peso
```

Isto vai retornar todas as observações da coluna peso, na forma de um vetor.

Caso não consiga resolver o problema da importação, pode converter fatores para números da seguinte forma:

```
animais$peso <- as.numeric(as.character(animais$peso))
```

Ou, um pouco mais eficiente:

```
animais$peso <- as.numeric(levels(animais$peso))[animais$peso]
```